# Do you get notifications for new email from your other Gmail accounts?

Tags: ios, gmail

I am new to iOS and from Android I am used to getting (g)mail notifications for all of my accounts. I have 4 connected to the Gmail app, though I only get notifications for the main one (the one I added first and is on default everytime I open the app). I checked the notification setting but there is nothing to configure. Is there a way to get notifications for every account?

I've seen one post here from about 8 years ago but I'm not sure if it is still relevant. I use the newest iOS on iPhone 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure notifications for each account in the Gmail app settings (this assumes notifications are on in iOS settings):

1. Open Gmail app
2. Tap hamburger icon in top left
3. Scroll to bottom
4. Tap “Settings”
5. Tap an account
6. Scroll to bottom
7. Tap “Notifications”
8. Select your notifications preference

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with two Gmail accounts I use. On my computer, I sent a message from account #1 to account #2, waited until I heard the tone on my iPhone and saw the notification on the screen, then sent an email from account #2 to account #1. Both times I heard the tone and got a lock-screen popup.

In Settings > Gmail I have this configuration:

[image]